# ng-repeat function called multiple times

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have written ng-repeat like below

```
<div  class="anchor" ng-repeat="race in races" ng-class="showdata (race)"></div>


  $scope.showdata = function(data)
  {
    var raceId = data.raceId;
    if(raceId == 66666666)
   {
    console.log(data);
    console.log('----- next ---')
   }
```

and data is something like this

[
    {
      "raceId": "434346"
    },
    {
      "raceId": "123456"
    },
    {
      "raceId": "222222"
    } ,
    {
      "raceId": "5555555"
    }
     ,
    {
      "raceId": "32423443"
    }
     ,
    {
      "raceId": "66666666"
    }
  ]

Ideally data should get printed only once as raceId 66666666 is only once. But i see object printed thrice. Is there any problem with it. Ideally it means it got called thrice with same data?

Comment: It's just the digest cycle running 3 times. Hence the 3 logs.

Comment: @tymeJV _ Is it normal or any issue with code. I am concerned bcos, i tot any problem with my code!!

Comment: It's normal - just Angular's internals at work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a side note from the comment by @tymeJV, which is clearly correct.

If you are looking to set a particular class based on one of the ng-repeat items, you can also use basic logic inside the `ng-class` itself.

For example:

```
<div  class="anchor" ng-repeat="race in races" ng-class="{'some-class': race.raceId === '66666666'"></div>
```

This will only apply the `some-class` to the race item you have listed in your code.

Comment: Nope its larger processing to be done. So i was worried about performance of my code, if i was doing anything wrong. Is it normal what it is happening?

Comment: I tend to avoid using function calls in html for angular. Even if you have larger processing, you should still be able to abstract it in such a way that you don't need to use function calls with `ng-class`. I suspect you are thinking about your problem the wrong way.